Statistical analysis of overlapping polygons using ArcGIS Pro
I have two features (call them X and Y), each consisting of hundreds of smaller polygons within a single U.S. state.
Is there a geographic statistical technique that can get at whether feature Y is significantly correlated with feature X?
As in, you're more likely to find feature Y near feature X than elsewhere.
Chi square or logistic regression analyses come to mind, but I have no idea how I would get the data prepared for those tests. I'm also not sure if those are appropriate for my question.
I'm working in ArcGIS Pro to visualize these shapefiles but was hoping to pull out the attribute tables and work in Python eventually (unless it's easier just to do everything in ArcGIS Pro).
